# Not able to render Visualforce page in google chrome

Tags: visualforce

not able to render visualforce page on google chrome getting below issue

[image]

Tried to follow [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pages_browser_security_settings.htm&type=5) link but still no luck and my browser is not blocking 3rd party cookies

would highly apricate if anyone would help me to get rid of this message?

Visualforce page

```
<apex:page>
<!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
<h1>Congratulations</h1>
This is your new Page
<!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Can you add your VF code so I can reproduce this behavior? What version of Chrome are you using?Is this intermittent or happens all the time? Also see https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000312846&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have updated the question.

Comment: Thanks, @gs650x. Can you also clarify from when are you seeing this issue? What version of Chrome are you using? Have you tried steps in https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000312846&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1